# Proving $A \implies B$ or $C$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

To show that a statement $A$ implies $B$ or $C$, is it sufficient to show that if $A$ and $ \neg B$ hold, then $C$ must hold?
It is clear in the case of a set where we have to show that $A$ is a subset of $B$ or $C$, showing the above must be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient

Comment: $A \implies B\lor C$ is a contingency (i.e. sometimes true, sometimes false). It is false if A is true and both B and C are false. It is true otherwise. (See truth table)

Answer (score 1):

An impliciation $P\Rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $\neg P \vee Q$. In your situation this means that $A\Rightarrow(B\vee C)$ is equivalent to
$$
\neg A \vee B\vee C.
$$
However, using [de Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you can also write this as
$$
\neg(A \wedge \neg B) \vee C
$$
which is then equivalent to
$$
(A \wedge \neg B) \Rightarrow C.
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the equivalence in the first line? I am not sure how it is true.

Comment: Given the truth values of $P$ and $Q$ there is only one case that renders $P\Rightarrow Q$ false: when $P$ is true but $Q$ is false. The same is true for $\neg P\vee Q$, it is only false when $P$ is true and $Q$ is false. You can just compare all four cases in a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication).